# Can't get image with ACF and Timber

Tags: php, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

It's my first time with Timber/Wordpress.

I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/navz-photo-gallery/) with Timber but I can't render any image.

I'm only getting the ids of the images:

```
{% set images = post.get_field('gallery_images') %} // "47,48"
```

I also try:

```
if (isset($post->hero_image) && strlen($post->hero_image)){
    $post->hero_image = new TimberImage($post->hero_image);
}
```

I looked at the [documentation](https://timber.github.io/timber/#acf-cookbook)

How can I get all the src of my images?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how or if your field gallery_images is nested further (via ACF).
If it's not nested it should work like this:

```
{% for image in post.get_field('gallery_images') %}
    <img src="{{ TimberImage(image).src }}" alt="" />
{% endfor %}
```